# ^[[A and ^[[B show up in python interpreter when I press arrow keys

Tags: python, ipython

What's going on? I tried iPython and the regular Python interpreter, both show ^[[A and ^[[B for the up and down arrows instead of previous commands.

**Platform:** Ubuntu 12.04.

**Python:** 2.7.3 installed with pythonbrew

**Terminal:** iTerm 2 on Mac OSX 10.6, connected over SSH.

Has never worked in the Python shell over SSH, but works locally.

Running locale outputs:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Platform? Terminal emulator? Locale?

Comment: This happens if you don't have `readline` or the equivalent installed.  I don't know what platform you have, or how you installed Python, so I have no idea what advice to give.

Comment: Did it _use_ to work or has it never worked for you?  That functionality comes from [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_readline) or similar library bundled with the interpreter.

Comment: Thanks, updated with more info.

Comment: In case you don't know: Ubuntu should already have Python 2.7 installed properly, so for most purposes, there's no need to use pythonbrew to get it.

Comment: @ThomasK, thanks. I use pythonbrew + virtual environments by default since I run tests with other Python versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you installed Python with pythonbrew, you must install the `libreadline-dev` package in your package manager *then* recompile Python.

The package is named `libreadline-dev` or something similar in most Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora...).  This step is not required on Gentoo or Arch systems, which always include dev support for libraries.

This step is also not necessary for Python that you install from the package manager.

**Footnote:** The locale is irrelevant.  The terminal emulator is irrelevant.  SSH is irrelevant.  I have never seen these factors affect line editing capabilities, although I suppose anything's possible.

**Footnote 2:** I'm going to submit a patch to the docs for pythonbrew, this is not the first time someone has complained about readline missing.  **Update:** [Pull request](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/pull/87) **Update 2:** Merged.

Comment: You sir, are my hero. Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`libreadline-dev` was not enough, what solved it for me is to install the `readline` package:

```
pip install readline
```